# UK Capital Gains tax and Income

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

If a UK resident makes a capital gain of £25000 and has a state pension of £6000 are they liable for any UK tax, given that there is a capital gains allowance and a tax allowance?

Comment: Which tax year, as that will affect the exact tax bands? (Though the answer is there'll be a tax liability regardless, as the total income is well above the standard tax allowance + capital gains allowance)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the tax year, the Capital Gains tax allowance is about £12,000 and the personal income tax allowance is about £12,500.

It looks like you [can't count unused personal income tax allowance against capital gains](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg10246):

> Unused Income Tax reliefs and allowances cannot be set against the net gains.

So there'll be tax owing on about £13,000 - at a rate of 10%, or 18% if the gain is from residential property.

To calculate the exact tax, follow the steps listed at https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/rates:

- Subtract the personal allowance (e.g. £12,500 for 2019-20) from your pension (£6,000). If this is a negative number, as in this case, treat it as 0.
- Deduct the Capital Gains allowance (e.g. £12,000) from the gain (£25,000) to get £13,000.
- Add it to your taxable income to check what tax band the result falls into. In this case you get £13,000 which is well within the basic rate band. You'll pay 10% or 18% tax on this amount.

Comment: I'm not (yet) convinced that unused Personal Allowance carries over like this (i.e. taxable income is negative), and even if it _can_ be carried over, I _think_ that the calculation at step 4 of the page you link is only to determine which CGT band you fall under (10/18% vs 20/28%)... I not convinced that it can actually reduce the _amount_ that is charged at that rate.  But I could easily be wrong... I'll dig.

Comment: So far I've found [Can unused personal allowances be set against a chargeable capital gain?](https://www.taxation.co.uk/articles/2017-02-14-336016-readers-forum-taxing-gain) on Taxation.couk which asks an almost identical question, but unfortunately cuts-off just after indicating conflicting advice, but before providing an answer... (the full article is only available to subscribers!)

Comment: @TripeHound I'm pretty sure it does, because AIUI the principle is that capital gains are taxed as income except that there's an extra allowance and the rate is lower.

Comment: @TripeHound actually I think you're right, see https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg10246